# I want a way to call the html code present in js on the same page with another html code

Tags: javascript

I want a way to call the html code present in js on the same page with another html code.

For example, I want to call this form found in js codes:

```
<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "<form autocomplete='off' name='contact-form' spellcheck='false'><input autocomplete='name' class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' required='required' type='text'/><i class='fa fa-user'></i><b>الاسم</b><input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' required='required' type='text'/><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i><b>بريد إلكتروني</b><textarea autocomplete='email' class='contact-form-email-message notr' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' required='required'></textarea><i class='fa fa-quote-right'></i><b>رسالة</b><input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='إرسال'/><div class='contact-state'><p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'></p><p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'></p></div><div class='clear'></div></form>" );
</script>
```

I want to call the form when I'm putting this div:

```
<div id="new-projects"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot call HTML code. You can't call a form either. Can you rephrase your question? The snippet you have isn't any valid syntax I recognise. What kind of system is this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: I want to retrieve long html code using shorter html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your JS is called before the DOM (the page described with HTML syntax) is loaded.
You'll need something like this is your first snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#new-projects form" ).html( "<form autocomplete='off' name='contact-form' spellcheck='false'><input autocomplete='name' class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' required='required' type='text'/><i class='fa fa-user'></i><b>الاسم</b><input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' required='required' type='text'/><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i><b>بريد إلكتروني</b><textarea autocomplete='email' class='contact-form-email-message notr' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' required='required'></textarea><i class='fa fa-quote-right'></i><b>رسالة</b><input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='إرسال'/><div class='contact-state'><p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'></p><p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'></p></div><div class='clear'></div></form>" );
});
```

with

```
<div id="new-projects">
  <form></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would change ‘load’ to ‘html’ , load seems unneeded.

Then to reference the form:

‘$(“#new-projects form”)’

Answer (score 0):

Put your html (`<form ...`) in a .html file (like xxx.html) then call `$( "#new-projects" ).load('xxx.html');`